# How to get variable between 3 page of PHP

Tags: php, html

I have 3 page PHP

page1.php

```
<form method="post" action="page2.php">
    <input type="number" name="x">
    <button type="submit" name="submit2">submit</button>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit2']))
{
    $n = $_POST['x'];
}
else
{
    echo "num wasn't obtained?"
}
?>

<form method="post" action="page3.php">
    <?php for ($i=0; $i < $n ; $i++) { ?>
    <select name="text<?php echo $i+1 ?>" required>
        <option value="asdf">asdf</option>
        <option value="qwer">qwer</option>
    </select>
    <?php } ?>
    <button type="submit" name="submit3">submit</button>
```

what code should I use in page3.php to get that x variable from page1.php

in page3.php I want to echo that text from page2.php based on x

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit3']))
{
    for ($i=0; $i < $n; $i++) #where $n is x from page1.php 
    {
        $l$i = $_POST['text$i'];
    }
```

Comment: either hidden form fields or sessions.

Comment: can u tell me how?

Comment: Can you go do your own research first please, when you are given the appropriate keywords?

Comment: `$l$i` isn't valid anyway. Why not just do `<select name="text[]">` and then on page3 you can just `var_dump($_POST['text'])` and see how you get an array? Nifty!